# using 64 bit COM object in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com, atl

Can a 64 bit Delphi application access a 64 bit ATL COM object?

My 64 bit Delphi app can access a 32 bit COM and the 32 bit type library can be imported, but trying to import a 64 bit version does not find anything in the registry, and changing the TGUID's by hand doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If the 64bit app cannot find the 64bit COM object in the Registry, then the COM object is not registered correctly. It should not be finding the 32bit COM object to begin with, unless it is registered as an out-of-process server for both 32bit and 64bit.